# How to make a zigzag line in JavaSript OpenLayers

Tags: javascript

I want to use the "ZigZag" border to differentiate certain areas on the map

When I use Style-Stroke to generate borders everything works fine.

The problem occurs when I try to use a function that generates a border in "ZigZag". Then I get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: style.getImage is not a function"

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Draw from 'ol/interaction/Draw'
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import {Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source';
import {Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';
import {Fill, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import LineString from 'ol/geom/LineString';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';



var arrayEstiloTracosPontos =
[
  new Style(
  {
      stroke: new Stroke(
      {
          width: 5,
          color: 'black'
          , zIndex: 0
      })
      , fill: new Fill( { color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)' } )
  }),
  new Style(
  {
      stroke: new Stroke(
      {
          width: 3,
          color: 'white',
          lineCap: 'butt',
          lineDash: [9, 9]
          , zIndex: 1
      })
  })
];


var colecaoEstilos = 
{
  'Polygon': funcaoEstiloBordaZigZag(4, 2, '#f00'),  // red
  'MultiPolygon': arrayEstiloTracosPontos
};


var objetoGeoJson = 
{
  'type': 'FeatureCollection',
  'crs': 
  {
    'type': 'name',
    'properties': 
    {
      'name': 'EPSG:3857'
    }
  },
  'features':     // array funcionalidades com 7 geometrias ///////////////////
  [
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': 
      {
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': 
        [
          [
            [-5e6, -1e6], [-3e6, -1e6], [-4e6, 1e6], [-5e6, -1e6]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': 
      {
        'type': 'MultiPolygon',
        'coordinates': 
        [
          [
            [
              [-5e6, 6e6], [-3e6, 6e6], [-3e6, 8e6], [-5e6, 8e6], [-5e6, 6e6]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [-2e6, 6e6], [0, 6e6], [0, 8e6], [-2e6, 8e6], [-2e6, 6e6]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [1e6, 6e6], [3e6, 6e6], [3e6, 8e6], [1e6, 8e6], [1e6, 6e6],
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },    
  ]
};


var funcaoEstilo = function (funcionalidade) 
{
  // retorna os tipos das geometrias
  return colecaoEstilos[ funcionalidade.getGeometry().getType() ];
};


var objetoGradeCamada = new TileLayer( { source: new OSM() } );


var objetoVetorFonte = new VectorSource(
{
  features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures( objetoGeoJson )
});


var objetoVetorCamada = new VectorLayer(
{
  source: objetoVetorFonte,
  style: funcaoEstilo
});
![![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KtcQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpM2H.png)
function funcaoEstiloBordaZigZag(larguraLinha, strokeWidth, colorir) 
{
  var estiloBordaZigZag = new Style(
  {
    stroke: new Stroke(
    {
      color: colorir,
      width: strokeWidth
    })
  });

  return function(feature, resolution) 
  {
    var lines = [];
    var geom = feature.getGeometry();

    if (geom.getType() == "LineString") 
    {
      for (var line = 0; line < 2; line++) 
      {
        var dist = larguraLinha * resolution * (line - 1/2);
        var coords = [];
        var counter = 0;

        geom.forEachSegment(function(from, to) 
        {
          var angle = Math.atan2(to[1] - from[1], to[0] - from[0]);

          var newFrom = 
          [
            Math.sin(angle) * dist + from[0],
            -Math.cos(angle) * dist + from[1]
          ];

          var newTo = [ Math.sin(angle) * dist + to[0], -Math.cos(angle) * dist + to[1] ];

          coords.push(newFrom);
          coords.push(newTo);

          if (coords.length > 2) 
          {
            var intersection = math.intersect(coords[counter], coords[counter+1], coords[counter+2], coords[counter+3]);

            coords[counter+1] = (intersection) ? intersection : coords[counter+1];
            coords[counter+2] = (intersection) ? intersection : coords[counter+2];
            counter += 2;
          }
        });

        lines.push( new LineString(coords) );
      }

      var length = geom.getLength();
      var intervals = Math.ceil(length / (larguraLinha * resolution));
      var coords = [];

      coords.push( geom.getCoordinateAt(0) );

      for (var i= 0; i < intervals; i++) 
      {
        coords.push(
          lines[i % 2].getClosestPoint(
            geom.getCoordinateAt((2 * i + 1) / (intervals * 2))
          )
        );
      }

      coords.push( geom.getCoordinateAt(1) );

      estiloBordaZigZag.setGeometry( new LineString(coords) );

      return estiloBordaZigZag;
    }
  };
}

var mapa = new Map(
  {
    layers: [ objetoGradeCamada, objetoVetorCamada ],
    target: 'mapa',
    view: new View( { center: [0, 0], zoom: 2 } ),
    type: 'LineString'
  });
```